# Creating a query for trapping datetime in multiple room PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a scheduling system

I have a query to create a error if the date and time has already been scheduled

my problem is i have multiple room and if i create a schedule in one room if it is the same with the other room it wont add

```
function save_schedule(){
    extract($_POST);
    $data = "";
    foreach($_POST as $k=> $v){
        if($k != 'id'){
            if(!empty($data)) $data.=", ";
            $data.=" {$k} = '{$v}'";
        }
    }
    if(strtotime($datetime_end) < strtotime($datetime_start)){
        $resp['status'] = 'failed';
        $resp['err_msg'] = "Date and Time Schedule is Invalid.";
    }else{
        $d_start = strtotime($datetime_start);
        $d_end = strtotime($datetime_end);
        $chk = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM `schedule_list` where (('{$d_start}'   
        Between unix_timestamp(datetime_start) and unix_timestamp(datetime_end)) or ('{$d_end}' 
        Between unix_timestamp(datetime_start) and unix_timestamp(datetime_end))) ".(($id > 0) ? "
        and id !='{$id}' " : ""))->num_rows;
        if($chk > 0){
            $resp['status'] = 'failed';
            $resp['err_msg'] = "The schedule is conflict with other schedules.";
        }else{
            if(empty($id)){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `schedule_list` set {$data}";
            }else{
                $sql = "UPDATE `schedule_list` set {$data} where id = '{$id}'";
            }
            $save = $this->conn->query($sql);
            if($save){
                $resp['status'] = 'success';
                $this->settings->set_flashdata('success', " Schedule successfully saved.");
            }else{
                $resp['status'] = 'failed';
                $resp['sql'] = $sql;
                $resp['qry_error'] = $this->conn->error;
                $resp['err_msg'] = "There's an error while submitting the data.";
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($resp);
}
```

can anyone help me in this query

```
$chk = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM `schedule_list` where (('{$d_start}'   
    Between unix_timestamp(datetime_start) and unix_timestamp(datetime_end)) or ('{$d_end}' 
    Between unix_timestamp(datetime_start) and unix_timestamp(datetime_end))) ".(($id > 0) ? "
    and id !='{$id}' " : ""))->num_rows;
```

[assembly_hall table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yFoE.png)

[schedule_list table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVSMI.png)

Comment: Please provide example in text, hard to follow what you are trying to do here. Also you are open to SQL injections, use prepared statements and parameterize

Comment: Without a `$room_id`, I wouldn't considered this as a "scheduling system".

Comment: ^ as above. You will need to create a `room_id` (or similar) column on the table. You can then parse this through as a part of the `$_POST` data. That room_id should also be used to filter on your SQL query that checks for conflicts.

Comment: @Rylee thank i already solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the SQL injection problems, I see a couple of issues:

Your query should be only looking for conflicts for the assembly_hall_id it will be inserting; as is, it looks for conflicting schedules for any assembly hall.

Your conflict check is incorrect; if a hall is reserved for 1pm-2pm and someone tries to reserve it for 12pm-3pm, you don't detect it, because neither the new start nor end is in the reserved range.  Correct conflict checking is done with:

```
least(datetime_end, new end value) > greatest(datetime_start, new start value)
```